# How to delete the texts and formulars on the site

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, button

I have two questions but, as they are so similar, I ask it as one question:

Question 1:
I have made text and a formular with html. If somebody klicks on one button, all text must vanish. Here is my code:

```
Hello here is example text
<form action="example.php" method="POST">
First name:
<input type="Text" name="Name" size="50" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="20"><br>
Last Name:
<input type="Text" name="LName" size="50" placeholder="Last Name" maxlength="200"><br>
<input type="Submit" value="Register">
<br><br><br><br><br>
Delete all:
<button onclick="Delete()">Make all Vanish!</button>


function Delete() {
//Here comes the code to vanish the formular, the text and the button itselve!

}
```

The second question is really easy. Is there a possibility to make not only formulars and server-based text but also javascript text (I mean)

```
<script>
document.write("Here is the javascript text");
</script>
```

vanish?
To see what I mean, here comes the full code:

```
Hello here is example text<br>
<script>
document.write("And here is some javascript text");
</script><br>

<form action="example.php" method="POST">
First name:
<input type="Text" name="Name" size="50" placeholder="First Name" maxlength="20"><br>
Last Name:
<input type="Text" name="LName" size="50" placeholder="Last Name" maxlength="200"><br>
<input type="Submit" value="Register">
<br><br><br><br><br>
Delete all:
<button onclick="Delete()">Make all Vanish!</button>

function Delete() {
//Here comes the code to vanish the formular, the HTML or PHP text and the //button itselve!

//Here comes the code to vanish the javascript text (or the best way would be //one code to vanish all)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to identify what text is added by `document.write` and the one that is written in your html file.

Your both the questions basically needs this line to be added in your `Delete()` function

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML = ''
```

Which obviously also makes the whole body empty.

I will suggest to have wrapper divs around your code structure which can help in demarcation.